# Magento not using appropriate URL - 404 Page not found

Tags: magento, wamp

I have a magento site running locally using WAMP and it works great. However I need to create a different site so I created a folder for this new site under htdocs.

In that folder I loaded the Magento files. 
Created a new database for newsite with all rights in phpmyadmin.
Went to the localhost:8888/newsite and started Magento installation wizard.
In the configuration section of the wizard I entered all the info required: db name, user, password. For URL Base I used the default (http://localhost:8888/newsite). Selected allow charts and Allow apache rewrites. Finished installing magento.

Now magento is running on newsite. I can see the front and back-end of the site.

Here is the problem:  When I create a category and/or subcategory, magento does create the menu link but when I click any category, the browser takes me to a **404 not found**. Upon analyzing the URL that took me there i see that the URL is :  http://localhost:8888/newsite/category.html  BUT by adding "**index.php**" into the URL (http://localhost:8888/newsite/**index.php**/category.html , the page does work!
So this means magento **IS** creating the page for the category but the linking is somewhat wrong.

Now, I've been making sure that rewrite is enabled and after all, the other site I mentioned I have is working properly, so I assume rewrite is properly enabled.

So I need help finding:

Why is one site working and the other isn't?
How can I fix this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you haven't copied over the .htaccess file (in your Magento root folder). You need this file for the Apache rewrites to work.

Comment: I just extracted the files straight from the downloaded magento package. i don't see any .htaccess not even in the folder of the site that works. Can you explain it to me in a bit more detail?  Thanks

Comment: All Magento installations come with a .htaccess file. It's in the same directory as index.php. If you don't see it, then Windows could be hiding it from you. Make sure you have "Show hidden files..." selected in your folder options.

Comment: The .htaccess file routes all (technically speaking, most) requests to index.php, so you don't need /index.php/ in all of your URLs. However, if you cannot get this working, you can always disable Apache (Web Server) rewrites in the system admin (General->Web->Search Engine Optimizations). When this option is set to "No", Magento adds /index.php/ to all your store URLs.